# Pass function through x-tag accessors

Tags: javascript, html, x-tag

I am trying to use x-tag accessors but I'm not finding a good documentation about them.I would like to pass a function through an accessor and write something like this:

```
<my-element logic="myFunction()"></my-element>
```

And I want to save that function and use it later. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I'll give it a shot.  If you are trying to make some logic available on all `<my-element>` tags, use the `methods` object, like this:

```
xtag.register('my-element', {
    methods: {
        logic: function (a) {
            return a * 2;
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to be able to assign `logic` to each instance of `<my-element>` individually, then you could use a standard (non-attribute) accessor, and do so implicitly.

```
xtag.register('my-element', {
    accessors: {
        logic: {}
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<my-element id="test"></my-element>
```

Set logic for one instance of `<my-element>`

```
var el = document.querySelector('my-element#test');
el.logic = function (a) {
    return a * 2;
};
```

If you want to use an attribute to set the value of `logic` to a global function, you could do this:

Example global function

```
function myFunction(a) {
    return a * 2;
}
```

Component

```
xtag.register('my-element', {
    accessors: {
        logic: {
            attribute: {},
            get: function () {
                return this._logic;
            },
            set: function (v) {
                this._logic = window[v] || null;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Usage (HTML)

```
<my-element logic="myFunction"></my-element>
```

Usage (JS)

```
var el = document.querySelector('my-element');
el.logic(2); // 4
```